# Problema con el Gradle al correr el proyecto en flutter en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, flutter

Acabo de iniciar un proyecto de **flutter** con el Android Studio, y asi básico como estaba le de a run, para que lo corriera en el emulador de **Genymotion**. Al intentar correrlo, salta un error. Tengo todo instalado, ya reinicie los programas y el 
"**Flutter doctor**" no tira ningun error

**El error:**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Google Nexus 6, 8 0, API 26, 1440x2560 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
* Error running Gradle:
Exit code 1 from: C:\Users\Tomas\AndroidStudioProjects\mi_app\android\gradlew.bat app:properties:
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Tomas\AndroidStudioProjects\mi_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 25

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
   > Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Ya modifique el archivo sin embargo no figuraba en $flutterRoot (No habia ninguna carpeta con ese nombre), pero el nombre del archivo era el mismo y solo agregue google(), lo que figura ahora es esto:

Launching lib\main.dart on Google Nexus 6, 8 0, API 26, 1440x2560 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
timeout waiting for the application to start  <-----Aqui el error
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
D/EGL_emulation( 2293): eglCreateContext: 0xdaec1ce0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
E/EGL_emulation( 2293): tid 2345: eglSurfaceAttrib(1210): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer( 2293): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xd85a4b40, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
D/EGL_emulation( 2293): eglCreateContext: 0xdaec1c20: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/        ( 2293): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xc2caca40, tid 2311
W/        ( 2293): Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: 
Syncing files to device Google Nexus 6, 8 0, API 26, 1440x2560...

Igualmente el emulador ahora SI se ejecuta.

[image: Segunda imagen]

Comment: Podrás subir el detalle de tu Gradlew a nivel Android y App ?? seguro eso nos va a dar más detalle. Por otro lado , actualizaste recientemente?

Comment: Tengo un error similar * What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'C:\Descomprimir flutter\Visual projectos\flutter_application_1\android\app\build.gradle'.
> startup failed: build file 'C:\Descomprimir flutter\Visual projectos\flutter_application_1\android\app\build.gradle': 68: expecting '}', found '' @ line 68, column 1. 1 error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Es un error con la última versión de Flutter, sin embargo ya enviaron el PR y ya está desplegado en el channel master, no tengo idea para cuando estará en dev/beta.

si no quieres esperar, puedes solucionarlo de la siguiente manera:

Ubica el archivo `gradle-wrapper.properties` dentro de android/gradle y usa la siguiente versión de gradle:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Luego ubica la ruta de tu flutter sdk ($flutterRoot) y edita este archivo:

```
$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle
```

Verifica y cambia para que tengas estos repositorios y dependencias:

```
     buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Como se cambian los repositorios y dependencias??

Comment: ahí puse  repositories  y dependencies, reemplazalo por el que tengas en el archivo que te indiqué

Comment: Aparentemente estaria mejor, si embargo me tira un :timeout waiting for the application to start. Que significa?

Comment: modificaste el archivo correcto? puedes mostrarnos el log que aparece , quizas si lo agregas en tu pregunta para mejor lectura

Comment: Hecho. 
Aclaracion: La carpeta que tendria que tener como nombre  $flutteRoot, me figura solo como flutter

Comment: cambiaste el gradle-wrapper.properties ??

Comment: Desinstala la app , luego en el terminal escribe:  flutter clean ,    luego flutter packages get , e intenta correr nuevamente

Comment: Por cierto, este issue ya fue resuelto, está listo en dev y master channel, solo falta que deployen en beta . https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/23397

Answer (score 0):

Ese error es porque no te está detectando la libreria de google en esta sección:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}
```